# Brute force improvement over generating permutations?

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to improve a brute force algorithm for letters of the English alphabet [a-z][A-Z] and numbers [0-9]. The length of the generated permutations should be 8. So far, I've built a simple brute force iteration with Ruby and later I broke down the master iteration to smaller ones of 100_000 items each. Also, I am creating a Thread for each one and use jruby to support native O/S threading. Please don't advice me to work with C or other languages, I just want to take Ruby to its limits for now.

My stats so far are:

- ====> 218,340,105,584,896 items will be generated
- ~867,080 permutations/sec
- will approximately take 2914 days to complete.

This may sound silly but I am trying to improve the brute force. I am thinking of the following things:

- Brute force generates a lot of reversed same ones. For example: [ abcdefgh <=> hgfedcba ]. How could I process these ?
- There are also repeated "parts" inside a permutation. Example: "abababab" is "ab" * length/2 or "a1e4a1e4" is "a1e4"*length/4.

By searching the net I couldn't find any brute force "improvements". Is there any hope?

Comment: Why do you care about permutations? `abcdefgh` and `hgfedcba` are different passwords.

Comment: Your fundamental problem is that you do 218,340,105,584,896 of anything. No smarter algorithm will help when it still has to produce that many results. Even if it takes a single clock cycle (which is literally impossible with common Ruby implementations, and practically impossible for any interesting operation) that's still going to take a long time. Not quite as physically impossible as brute forcing 2^256 possibilities but still a lot, simply because there are so many possible passwords.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I didn't say anything about passwords. I need all permutations.

Comment: If you want permutations, why don't you use a standard algorithm that only outputs permutations? But how is generating permutations related to brute-force? Also what do you mean by permutation? Every permutation of [a-z][A-Z][0-9] has length 62, not 8. Do you simply want outputs where each character is unique?

Comment: @CodesInChaos do you have any algorithm to suggest? Also, how is permutations not related to brute force? If you want to brute force a PIN number, it's about [0-9] numbers possible permutations. But there is a chance I might be telling something wrong so please correct me.

Comment: Or do you want all distinct subsets of size 8? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: @ChrisV. Normally every possible sequence of characters from the chosen set is a valid password/PIN. e.g. `abcdefgh` is distinct and unrelated to `hgfedcba`. So unless you have some restrictions on what's valid, all the talk about permutations or repetitions is irrelevant.

Comment: @CodesInChaos so I want create them all and store them in a file/db instead of creating them every time I want to brute force. The reason for what I want this is not relevant but I am mentioning it to make clear why creating strings is different to using them.

Comment: @ChrisV. So you want to generate a file that's 1700 TB in size and which probably takes longer to read than simply recomputing them on the fly?

Comment: @CodesInChaos not really, that's why I am asking. But I guess that people should have already researched this and found out more than I do. I was hoping to create some rainbow tables but I see there's no hope also for disk space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no hope. The fastest thing you can do is replace characters in an array instead of generating a new string object at each iteration. But whatever processing you plan to do with each permutation will presumably take considerably longer than it took to generate the permutation in the first place.